# JAX WS services

Tags: xml, jax-ws

I want create JAX WS services, Where I have a xml file which will be send on particular URL and that URL will respond some information. Now I want to perform this service using JAX WS. I could not place main purpose of JAX WS.

Comment: Could you elaborate what you're trying to do?

Comment: I want to create web service using JAX WS. The scenario will be, We have service provider's URL and we want to send XML file format to that URL and get some response on our side using JAX WS.

Comment: I think you may want to take a look at this framework https://jersey.java.net/